# Android - Scroll and Bottom Sheet in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-coordinatorlayout, bottom-sheet

first of all I am not familiar with CoordinatorLayouts, I have a fragment that contain several scrollable CardViews, when I tried to add a bottom sheet I got the **Bottom Sheet must be a child of a coordinatorLayout** error, so I added a coordinatorLayout and now I can't seem to be able to scroll anymore

**PS:** I tried replacing `ScrollView` with a `NestedScrollView` and it didn't work, I even tried to edit the XML tags order but nothing solved it, I still can't scroll

**Is there a way that I can use `Bottom Sheets` without having to use a `CoordinatorLayout` ??**

**Here's the XML layout fragment with ScrollView :**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 tools:context=".ThreeFragment" >
 <ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/MainScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="false">
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            style="@style/MyCardViewStyleTitle"
            android:id="@+id/view">
            <TextView
                android:text="I- Pure Vowels"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/MyCardViewStyleContent"
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
            <TextView
                android:text="Pronouncing : á"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                android:textSize="17dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:text="\n\nas in English father\nE.g.  ár ‘year’"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:textSize="40px"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
      <!-- more cardviews -->
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
 <!-- Bottom Sheet Layout-->
 <include layout="@layout/learn_more_sheet" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Here's the XML layout fragment with NestedScrollView :**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 tools:context=".ThreeFragment" >
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/MainScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="false">
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            style="@style/MyCardViewStyleTitle"
            android:id="@+id/view">
            <TextView
                android:text="I- Pure Vowels"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/MyCardViewStyleContent"
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
            <TextView
                android:text="Pronouncing : á"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                android:textSize="17dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:text="\n\nas in English father\nE.g.  ár ‘year’"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:textSize="40px"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
      <!-- more cardviews -->
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
 <!-- Bottom Sheet Layout-->
 <include layout="@layout/learn_more_sheet" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Main Activity XML layout**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  tools:context="com.incorp.anisvikernes.englishtonorse.MainActivity">
>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160px"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: Remove BottomSheetLayout from the fragment, and put it in the Activity under the ViewPager. Then put one `NestedScrollView` on the top of the fragment, with attributes like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
android:fillViewport="true">
```

To make the BottomSheet appear only in the fragment, you can do this:
Set visbility to `android:visiblity="gone"`, and in the fragment set it to visibile, like this:

```
var sheet = (View)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.{sheet});
sheet.setVisbility(view.Visible);
```

Then, in the other fragments you have, do the same, just with `sheet.setVisbility(view.Gone);`

To hide it when pressing on back, use this in **the Activity**:

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {

       if (sheet.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
    sheet.setVisbility(view.Gone);

    }
```

Comment: 1. Change android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollViewScrollView to android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.
2. Do you want each card to be able to scroll seperately, or do you want the whole view to be scollable?

Comment: for your first step, excuse me it is already `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView` and I want the whole view to be scrollable

Comment: @Sígvardr The code you posted has a typo error: android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollViewScrollView

Comment: you mea it should be like this : `<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>            <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>... </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout></android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>`

Comment: Yes. But try it both with the second one and without. And add app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" to both.

Comment: the scroll is still not functioning, by the way did I mention that I don't have an Action bar ??

Comment: I want the Bottom Sheet to be available only in that fragmen, is that possible in the code you provided ??

Comment: is it possible to hide a bottom sheet with the hard back button while it is expanded ?? (don't forget that I'm working in a fragment) ??

Comment: Before we do that, I started having this problem with the behind code related to the BottomSheet I started to get NullPointerException (I tried different activities and fragments including the main layout but nothing solved it)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121462/discussion-between-amitairos-and-sigvardr-olavrsson).